# Show text/plain even if both text/plain and text/html are sent

Tags: gmail, html, text

Someone sent me an e-mail in both text and HTML, with embedded (attached) images.
One of the images is 3311-pixel wide. As a consequence, gmail widens the text box accordingly, which makes the e-mail very hard to read. As an alternative to [not showing the image](https://superuser.com/q/529303/133195), is there a way to force gmail to show the text/plain version rather than the text/html version, when the e-mail is sent in both formats?

Comment: Please don’t cross-post from other SE sites; flag the question there to be migrated instead of reposting it.

Comment: It's not a cross-post. This is a different question.